# C# code to generate entire spherical coordinates

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to generate an entire spherical coordinates, starting from phi that ranging from 0 - pi degrees and theta ranging from 0 to 2pi degrees. I tried nested for loop to generate x, y, z coordinate but gives me an error that says "cannot convert double[] to double". Not sure how I can fix this issue, your help would be very appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var phi = Enumerable.Range(0, 181).ToArray();
        var theta = Enumerable.Range(0, 361).ToArray();

        double[] phiconverted = new double[181];
        double[] thetaconverted = new double[361];


        for (int i = 0; i < phi.Length; i++)
        {
            phiconverted[i] = phi[i] * Math.PI / 180;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < theta.Length; i++)
        {
            thetaconverted[i] = theta[i] * Math.PI / 180;

        }

        double x, y, z;

        for (int i = 0; i < phiconverted.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<thetaconverted.Length; j++)
            {
                x = 10 * Math.Sin(thetaconverted) * Math.Cos(phiconverted);
                y = 10 * Math.Sin(thetaconverted) * Math.Sin(phiconverted);
                z = 10 * Math.Cos(thetaconverted);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Typo?  It looks like you forgot to use `i` and `j` in your loops when accessing your arrays...

Answer (score 2):

It's usually helpful to indicate which line your exception occurs at.  In this case, I'm assuming it's the `x=`, `y=` and `z=` lines.

The error you received indicates that you supplied a `double[]` (array) to a method (`Math.Sin` or `Math.Cos` in this case) that expected `double`.  The reason is you haven't specified which index in the array you're accessing.  It should probably be this:

```
 x = 10 * Math.Sin(thetaconverted[j]) * Math.Cos(phiconverted[i]);
 y = 10 * Math.Sin(thetaconverted[j]) * Math.Sin(phiconverted[i]);
 z = 10 * Math.Cos(thetaconverted[j]);
```